# Angular 7 nested module routing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, ionic4

I don't get how the routing with multiple nested modules works.
The RouteTree looks good and correct to me
[image]

It works till the "More" page. After clicking on ContactPage the url changes but the view doesn't render.

This is what my routers looks like:

**app.routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**tabs.routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'more',
                loadChildren: '../more/more.module#MorePageModule'
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'home',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'tabs/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {
}
```

**more.routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MorePage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'contact',
                component: ContactPage
            },
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MoreRouterModule {
}
```

**contact.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'contact',
    component: ContactPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [ContactPage],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class ContactPageModule {}
```

I don't know what the problem is. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to rewrite the following (in `more.routing.module`) :

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MorePage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'contact',
                component: ContactPage
            },
        ]
    }
];
```

using `loadChildren` like this:

```
children: [
    {
        path: 'contact',
        loadChildren: 'path/to/contact.module#ContactPageModule'
    },
]
```